# R programming concatenate every 3 rows and removing NA

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, na

I have this data frame with date column split into multiple rows. I want to concatenate or merge date rows and remove NAs from the other column

```
   df <- data.frame(date = rep(c("Nov","22","2012"),3),x = rep(c(NA,NA,12345),3))
        date    x
      1  Nov    NA
      2   22    NA
      3 2012 12345
      4  Nov    NA
      5   22    NA
      6 2012 12345
      7  Nov    NA
      8   22    NA
      9 2012 12345
```

Desired Result

```
     df <- data.frame(date = rep(("Nov 22 2012"),3),x  = rep(12345,3))

           date    x
  1 Nov 22 2012 12345
  2 Nov 22 2012 12345
  3 Nov 22 2012 12345
```

thank you

Comment: how do you get this data? Do you read it from some file? If so can you please provide the real input

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `zoo` package,

```
library(zoo)

new_df <- as.data.frame(rollapply(df, 3, by = 3, function(i)na.omit(c(i))))
final_df <- cbind(date = do.call(paste, new_df[1:3]), new_df[-c(1:3)])

final_df
#         date    V4
#1 Nov 22 2012 12345
#2 Nov 22 2012 12345
#3 Nov 22 2012 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `data.frame` structure is exactly like you show in example, this might help:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, 
              lapply(seq(1, nrow(df), by = 3),
                     function(i) 
                             data.frame(date = paste(df[i:(i+2),1], 
                                                     collapse = "-"),
                                        x = na.omit(df[i:(i+2), 2])
                                        )
                     )
              )
#df
#         date     x
#1 Nov-22-2012 12345
#2 Nov-22-2012 12345
#3 Nov-22-2012 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag` function in dplyr to paste the dates together, then remove NAs in the x column...

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(date=paste(lag(date,2),lag(date),date)) %>% filter(!is.na(x))
```